# Who is the last person to be dragged over the Sirat?

Tags: hadith, day-of-judgement, sahih-bukhari

I've come across a very intresting hadith from Sahih al-Bukhari.

> *Volume 9, Book 93, Number 532s*
>
> Some of the believers will cross the bridge as quickly as the wink of
> an eye, some others as quick as lightning, a strong wind, fast horses
> or she-camels. So some will be safe without any harm; some will be
> safe after receiving some scratches, and some will fall down into Hell
> (Fire). The last person will cross by being dragged (over the
> bridge)."

The hadith describes the state of different groups of people who will cross the bridge **Sirat**. The last sentence especially emphasizes the last person to be dragged over the *Sirat*.

Who is that last person and why is that person mentioned without a further description?

Reference: https://www.thereligionofpeace.com/quran/bukhari/093-sbt.htm